# Installing Battlefield 3 Premium where Battlefield 3 "standard" already exists

Tags: battlefield-3

I want to install BF3 Premium on a PC that already has the standard edition of BF3 installed (via Origin).

Will installing the Premium edition be treated as an additional game or will it overwrite the original version installed i.e. upgrade it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, your BF3 CD-Keys are tied to your Origin account, meaning you will still download a 'standard' copy of BF3, but get access to extra stuff in game with your Account.

Therefore, its like an upgrade.

Comment: Correct. Battlefield 3 Premium is an 'add-on', much like a DLC. It is not a separate edition of the game

Comment: I'll suck it and see, should know by tomorrow.

Comment: Yup, you're just buying the ability to use certain things in game, you don't download anything additional. At least not yet, might be different once the DLCs are released.

Answer (score 0):

I bought battlefield 3 premium but had no disk space to install it. After that, I couldn't install the patches.

Well The solution to this issue is repairing the game several times inside Origin for the platform to fetch all the patches. In my case I had to repair the game 5+ times for armored kill to show up.

After the platform fetches all patches and installs them, you can play ^^